# what does it do this asignement in python

Tags: python

my question is about the sintaxys that is used by python , i have an example of code and i'm trying to understand it , here below the code and then my question:

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        # dictionary 
        self.dictionary = {}

    def function1(self):
        for key_ex in self.dictionary.keys():
            _ = self.function_example(key_ex)
        return self

    def function_example(self) -> bool:
        # do something return true or false
        return True
```

Into the function1 the assignment _ = self.function_example(key_ex) is something that i don't understand. Somebody can give some explanation of this please ?

Comment: This might help: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/role-underscore-python Also, a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/5254754

Comment: Thanks @Harshil the information in the link was very usefull.